# Taking a NULL value from the database and assigning to a Date variable

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, date

A stored procedure returns data about a user record including a nullable datetime column for their last login date. Which one is the better choice in dealing with the possibility for NULL values when trying to assign a .Net date variable?

```
    Try
        _LastLogin = CDate(DT.Rows(0)("LastLogin"))
    Catch ex As InvalidCastException
        _LastLogin = Nothing
    End Try
```

or

```
    If DT.Rows(0)("LastLogin") Is DBNull.Value Then
        _LastLogin = Nothing
    Else
        _LastLogin = CDate(DT.Rows(0)("LastLogin"))
    End If
```

**Edit**: I also forgot about the possibility of using a TryParse

```
    If Not Date.TryParse(DT.Rows(0)("LastLogin").ToString, _LastLogin) Then
        _LastLogin = Nothing
    End If
```

Which is the preferred method of handling possible `NULL` values from the database? Is there a better way than the three listed?

**Edit #2**: I have noticed that the `TryParse` method does not play nice when trying to assign to a `Nullable` type.

Comment: The problem with your TryParse method is that you'd get an exception thrown by the ToString method if "LastLogin" is null.

Comment: Kev: If I am not mistaken, calling ToString on a NULL retrieval will result in a blank string (at least that is how it has been performing for my other information pulled back and stored in strings). I may have to do another check on that, however.

Comment: Yes, DBNull.Value.ToString() return String.Empty

Comment: Kev: I just tested it by making another column's info (that is pulled back as string) NULL and it went through the debugger fine using .ToString and assigned a value of "" to the string variable.

Comment: If the underlying column is a string type (eg varchar etc) then you're quite correct, but I'm pretty sure ToString() non string types will throw an exception i.e. SQL datetime.

Comment: @TheTXI - yep you're right, I stand corrected. :)

Comment: @Kev: in the grand scheme of things the TryParse won't play nice if the underlying variable I'm assigning to is a nullable type.

Comment: @Kev: So you were not wrong in every sense.

Comment: @TheTXI - half wrong, half right - not a bad end to a Wednesday.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second code snippet is better. Exceptions are for exceptional cases, not cases you expect to happen. Plus, the intent is much better. It's clear that you are expecting DBNull to be a possible value and you want to handle it accordingly.

Also, you may have unintended consequences if the value is not null but not parseable (although this is likely to never happen).

Answer (score 2):

The second method is preferable because of the cost involved in throwing exceptions (especially if you expect the LastLogin field to be NULL on a regular basis).

Here is a good [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/kcwalina/archive/2005/03/16/396787.aspx) with more details about exceptions (see the part about Exceptions and Performance).

Answer (score 2):

I use the FixDBNull class:

```
Public Class FixDBNull(Of ItemType)    
    Public Shared Function Convert(ByVal data As Object) As ItemType
        If data IsNot System.DBNull.Value Then
            Dim obj As ItemType = Nothing

            Try
               obj = CType(data, ItemType)    
            Catch ex As Exception
                'do something with the conversion error
            End Try

            Return obj
        Else
            Return Nothing
        End If

End Function
End Class
```

then I can call it like this:

```
_LastLogin = FixDBNull(Of date).Convert( DT.Rows(0)("LastLogin"))
```

which will return either nothing or a date.

Answer (score 1):

in VB.net, it has to be Nullable(of Date)

here’s one way:

```
dim theDate as nullable(of Date)

    If theDate.HasValue Then
      'you can proceed
    Else
      'you must assign with DBNull.value
    End If
```

The database will also likely factor into what you can do.
MS Access will squalk about dates no matter what.  I eventually got the above to work, but I usually prefer to save dates as strings in Access.  It just makes for less hassle down the road.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [`TryCast`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyy863x8.aspx), which'll look something like this:

```
_LastLogin = TryCast(DT.Rows(0)("LastLogin"), Date?)
```